# Erro na parte do codigo: navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico, options=options)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep

options = Options()
options.headless = False #executar de forma visivel ou oculta

servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico, options=options)

link = "https://www.google.com/"
navegador.get(url=link)
sleep(5)
```

E ta dando esse erro

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\eleninha.santos\Desktop\ROBO1\1.ipynb Cell 1' in <cell line: 12>()
      9 options.headless = False #executar de forma visivel ou oculta
     11 servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
---> 12 navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico, options=options)
     14 link = "https://www.google.com/"
     15 navegador.get(url=link)

File c:\Users\eleninha.santos\Desktop\ROBO1\vrobo\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:70, in WebDriver.__init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, service, keep_alive)
     67 if not service:
     68     service = Service(executable_path, port, service_args, service_log_path)
---> 70 super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
     71                                 port, options,
     72                                 service_args, desired_capabilities,
     73                                 service_log_path, service, keep_alive)

File c:\Users\eleninha.santos\Desktop\ROBO1\vrobo\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py:92, in ChromiumDriver.__init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, service, keep_alive)
     89 self.service.start()
     91 try:
---> 92     RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
     93         self,
     94         command_executor=ChromiumRemoteConnection(
     95             remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     96             browser_name=browser_name, vendor_prefix=vendor_prefix,
     97             keep_alive=keep_alive, ignore_proxy=_ignore_proxy),
     98         options=options)
     99 except Exception:
    100     self.quit()

File c:\Users\eleninha.santos\Desktop\ROBO1\vrobo\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:275, in WebDriver.__init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    273 self._authenticator_id = None
    274 self.start_client()
--> 275 self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)

File c:\Users\eleninha.santos\Desktop\ROBO1\vrobo\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:365, in WebDriver.start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    363 w3c_caps = _make_w3c_caps(capabilities)
    364 parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps}
--> 365 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    366 if 'sessionId' not in response:
    367     response = response['value']

File c:\Users\eleninha.santos\Desktop\ROBO1\vrobo\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:430, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    428 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    429 if response:
--> 430     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    431     response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    432         response.get('value', None))
    433     return response

File c:\Users\eleninha.santos\Desktop\ROBO1\vrobo\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:211, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    209     value = response['value']
    210 if isinstance(value, str):
--> 211     raise exception_class(value)
    212 if message == "" and 'message' in value:
    213     message = value['message']

WebDriverException: Message: <html><head>
<meta type="copyright" content="Copyright (C) 1996-2019 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>ERRO: A URL requisitada não pode ser recuperada</title>
<style type="text/css"><!-- 
 /*
 * Copyright (C) 1996-2019 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors
 *
 * Squid software is distributed under GPLv2+ license and includes
 * contributions from numerous individuals and organizations.
 * Please see the COPYING and CONTRIBUTORS files for details.
 */

/*
 Stylesheet for Squid Error pages
 Adapted from design by Free CSS Templates
 http://www.freecsstemplates.org
 Released for free under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License
*/

/* Page basics */
* {
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

html body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #efefef;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #1e1e1e;
}

/* Page displayed title area */
#titles {
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    background: url('/squid-internal-static/icons/SN.png') no-repeat left;
}

/* initial title */
#titles h1 {
    color: #000000;
}
#titles h2 {
    color: #000000;
}

/* special event: FTP success page titles */
#titles ftpsuccess {
    background-color:#00ff00;
    width:100%;
}

/* Page displayed body content area */
#content {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
}

/* General text */
p {
}

/* error brief description */
#error p {
}

/* some data which may have caused the problem */
#data {
}

/* the error message received from the system or other software */
#sysmsg {
}

pre {
}

/* special event: FTP / Gopher directory listing */
#dirmsg {
    font-family: courier, monospace;
    color: black;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#dirlisting {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
#dirlisting tr.entry td.icon,td.filename,td.size,td.date {
    border-bottom: groove;
}
#dirlisting td.size {
    width: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/* horizontal lines */
hr {
    margin: 0;
}

/* page displayed footer area */
#footer {
    font-size: 9px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}


body
:lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-serif; float: right; }
:lang(he) { direction: rtl; }
 --></style>
</head><body id="ERR_CONNECT_FAIL">
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERRO</h1>
<h2>A URL requisitada não pôde ser recuperada</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>O seguinte erro foi encontrado ao tentar recuperar a URL: <a href="http://localhost:53893/session">http://localhost:53893/session</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Conexão para ::1 falhou.</b></p>
</blockquote>

<p id="sysmsg">O sistema retornou: <i>(60) Operation timed out</i></p>

<p>O host ou rede remota pode estar fora do ar. Por favor, faça a requisição novamente.</p>

<p>Seu administrador do cache é <a href="mailto:chamados.maisvalor@grupomaisvalor.com.br?subject=CacheErrorInfo%20-%20ERR_CONNECT_FAIL&amp;body=CacheHost%3A%20localhost%0D%0AErrPage%3A%20ERR_CONNECT_FAIL%0D%0AErr%3A%20(60)%20Operation%20timed%20out%0D%0ATimeStamp%3A%20Wed,%2022%20Jun%202022%2019%3A07%3A17%20GMT%0D%0A%0D%0AClientIP%3A%20172.16.0.109%0D%0AServerIP%3A%20localhost%0D%0A%0D%0AHTTP%20Request%3A%0D%0APOST%20%2Fsession%20HTTP%2F1.1%0AAccept-Encoding%3A%20identity%0D%0AContent-Length%3A%20164%0D%0AAccept%3A%20application%2Fjson%0D%0AContent-Type%3A%20application%2Fjson%3Bcharset%3DUTF-8%0D%0AUser-Agent%3A%20selenium%2F4.2.0%20(python%20windows)%0D%0AConnection%3A%20keep-alive%0D%0AHost%3A%20localhost%3A53893%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A">chamados.maisvalor@grupomaisvalor.com.br</a>.</p>

<br>
</div>

<hr>
<div id="footer">
<p>Gerado Wed, 22 Jun 2022 19:07:17 GMT por localhost (squid)</p>
<!-- ERR_CONNECT_FAIL -->
</div>
</body></html>
```

Alguem pode ajudar a resolver

Answer (score -2):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class Navegador():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.chrome_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=self.chrome_service, options=options)

    def abrir(self):
        try:
            self.driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
            return self.driver
        except Exception as e:
            raise("Erro ao abrir o navegador: " + str(e))

    def fazer_logout(self):
        self.driver.quit()
    
options=Options()
#options.add_argument("--window-size=1366,780")
#options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('-ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('-ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--force-renderer-accessibility')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument('--enable-automation')
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).